# Install Viber on Debian 9

Tags: debian, apt

I'm trying to install viber on debian by use this command

```
#  wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
# unzip Viber.zip
# cd Viber
# ./Viber.sh
```

the first time I have this message

```
 Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module
```

after that I install it by

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

the other error is

> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

when use update I have the same problem I can not install `canberra-gtk-module`, how I can solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you see the two image I'm added it .......Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Comment: When click on Try Again ,there is no thing happen the same screen show

Comment: sara@sara:~$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules
libcanberra-gtk3-module.so  libcanberra-gtk-module.so  libcaribou-gtk-module.so

Comment: I use Debian buster/sid with libcurl4 installed, so libcurl3 cannot be installed. I followed the link that user290392 pointed out and, in order to be able to install, I tried and changed the libcurl3, which is specified in the DEBIAN/control, to libcurl4. It works just fine, till now...

Answer (score 2):

Is Viber.zip not for Windows?

If you go [here](https://www.viber.com/products/linux) you can get a `.deb` file.

Install it with Gdebi.

There are instructions for moving Viber and creating a symlink in Debian [here](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/06/09/how-to-install-viber-on-debian-64bit-gnu-linux/)

Comment: I tried to install Gdebi but it was wrong

Comment: Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change DEBIAN/control. For that you need to download viber.deb, extract the deb, fix DEBIAN/control and make a new deb package. It's described here:
https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?pid=71634#p71634

Just make sure to use root or fakeroot to preserve file permissions and ownership.